Angular not making http call on refresh
I'm making a simple angular application which allows users to make posts and view other users' posts. When first logging into the site, everything works as expected. The ngOnInit is called and the api returns the current posts. However, when I refresh the page, the ngOnInit is called, and I get a response in my subscribe method, but no HTTP call is actually sent. The response I get in my subscribe method is the data that was accurate at the time I built the application. When developing locally with ng serve, I do not get this issue, it's only after I build and host the application. The following is my ngOnInit function within the HomePage component.
ngOnInit() {
    console.log(1)
    this.http.get<any>(this.apiEndpoint + 'forum/get-forum-data')
    .pipe(catchError(error => {
      console.error('Error: ', error);
      console.log(3)
      return throwError(error);
    }))
    .subscribe(response => {
      console.log(2)
      this.userData = response.data;

      this.formGroups = this.userData.map((item: any) => this.createFormGroup(item));
      this.formGroups.sort((a, b) => {
        const dateA = a.get('dateCreated')?.value;
        const dateB = b.get('dateCreated')?.value;
        return dateB - dateA;
      });

      this.formGroups.forEach((item: any, index: number) => {
        if (this.likeArrayHasUsername(item)) {
          this.isLiked[index] = true;
        } else {
          this.isLiked[index] = false;
        }

        if (this.saveArrayHasUsername(item)) {
          this.isSaved[index] = true;
        }
        else {
          this.isSaved[index] = false;
        }
      });
    });
  }

Here is a link to the repository: https://github.com/zachpfaltzgraff/ForumWebsite
When refreshing the console output 1 and 2, but no Http call is made when looking under the network tab in developer tools.
When testing locally, it always works as expected.

Could it be some cashing issue? If so, it can be not about algular, but browser's behavior. You can try adding some unique query parameter tu\o URL each time, just for test.

I've tried running it in incognito mode on different browsers and it still behaves this way.  It shows data from the time I built not from when the last time angular successfully made the call, which I would expect if it were a caching problem. I will give it a try though

Adding a random query parameter worked! Thanks
